# How to set up Heartbeat to run a service only at one node

Tags: ubuntu, heartbeat, mysql

I have two Ubuntu 12.04 servers, which run mysql in a master-master setup, with mmm as manager. How can I set up heartbeat to make sure that mmm only runs at one node at the time?

***Edit** to explain more clearly

My setup:

```
  ---------VIP (10.0.0.123)------
  |                             |
Node1                         Node2
```

Where bot Node1 and Node2 run:

- Mysql
- Multi-Master Replication Manager for MySQL (mmm)
- Heartbeat

I only want a single write enabled Mysql node, and I can only have one mmm running at the time, else I'll get collision between the managers.

Comment: First of all `mysql` and `heartbeat` are not the same. So please describe what you are doing a little bit deeper. `mysql` has its own clustering abilities with no need for heartbeat...

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, heartbeat treats any script found in /etc/init.d/ as a service. As long as it has start and stop functions, with correct exit codes, I can just add on the service on the same line as the vIP definition:

```
loadbalancer1 10.0.0.123 service
```

Default behavior of heartbeat is then to make sure only a single node runs the service